# Why i get memory leak error if i use free()? c

Tags: c, memory, memory-leaks

Please help guys. I always get a memory leak even though im using free at the end. Can someone help?

code:

```
unsigned char* bmp_encrypt(const char* key, const char* text){
if(key == NULL || key[0] == '\0') {
    return NULL;
}
for(int i = 0; i < strlen(key); i++){
    if(!isalpha(key[i])){
        return NULL;
    }
}
if(text == NULL || text[0] == '\0') {
    return NULL;
}
char* rev = calloc(strlen(text)+1, sizeof(char));
char* vig = calloc(strlen(text)+1, sizeof(char));
rev = reverse(text);
vig = vigenere_encrypt(key, rev);
unsigned char* bit = calloc(strlen(vig)+1, sizeof(unsigned char));

bit = bit_encrypt(vig);

free(rev);
free(vig);

return bit;
```

}

Comment: Every call to `malloc`/`calloc` requires a corresponding call to `free`. However, in this case, you call `calloc` 3 times, but `free` only 2 times. Also, you must pass the return value from `malloc`/`calloc` to `free`, which you never do. Instead, you overwrite the variables with something else before passing them to `free`.

Answer (score 2):

You do this twice (different identifiers)

```
ptr = malloc(...); // let's say 0xDEADBEEF
ptr = fx();        // now ..... 0xBADC0FEE
```

The 2nd statement leaks the memory obtained from the 1st

```
free(ptr);      // free     0xBADC0FEE
                // where is 0xDEADBEEF ??
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. Now it makes more sense. Could you please help me implement your solution to my code?

Comment: Basic solution is **allocate only once**: only in the called function (`ptr = fx(); /* ... use ptr ... */ free(ptr);`) or only in the calling function (`ptr = malloc(); fx(ptr); /* ... use ptr ... */ free(ptr);`). I prefer the 2nd version because `malloc()` and `free()` are in the same function.